# Can't play lock.aiff inside SpringBoard.app

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

There is a sound file called lock.aiff in side SpringBoard.app if the iOS 7 SDK. The path for the sound file is as follows.

```
iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk/System/Library/CoreServices/SpringBoard.app/lock.aiffs
```

This is my code.

```
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle bundleWithIdentifier:@"com.apple.UIKit"] bundlePath];
    NSString *frameworkPath = [path stringByDeletingLastPathComponent];
    NSString *libraryPath = [frameworkPath stringByDeletingLastPathComponent];
    NSString *finalePath = [libraryPath stringByAppendingString:@"/CoreServices/SpringBoard.app/lock.aiff"];

    NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:finalePath];
    SystemSoundID soundID;
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge_retained CFURLRef)fileURL,&soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
```

`Value of the variable finalePath = "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk/System/Library/CoreServices/SpringBoard.app/lock.aiff"`

But I am unable to play this sound file on the simulator. Also so I can't play any of the sound file inside SpringBoard.app. But I can play any other file successfully. For example the sound file at the following location is playing well.

```
iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AOSNotification.framework/findme_alarm_2.aiff
```

My guess is that since the lock.aiffs is inside the SpringBoard.app, it causes some sort of a problem.So how can I play the lock.aiff file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot access the resources in another app bundle because of the sandboxed nature of iOS apps.

However, you can play the system sounds, such as the lock sound, like this:

```
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/lock.caf"]; 
SystemSoundID soundID;
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge_retained CFURLRef)fileURL,&soundID);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
```

Here's a full list of system sounds from iOS 7.0.2 that you can access:

```
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/Modern/airdrop_invite.caf
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/Modern/calendar_alert_chord.caf
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/Modern/camera_shutter_burst.caf
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/Modern/camera_shutter_burst_begin.caf
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/Modern/camera_shutter_burst_end.caf
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/Modern/sms_alert_aurora.caf
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/Modern/sms_alert_bamboo.caf
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/Modern/sms_alert_circles.caf
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/Modern/sms_alert_complete.caf
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/Modern/sms_alert_hello.caf
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/Modern/sms_alert_input.caf
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/Modern/sms_alert_keys.caf
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/Modern/sms_alert_note.caf
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/Modern/sms_alert_popcorn.caf
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/Modern/sms_alert_synth.caf
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/New/Anticipate.caf
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/New/Bloom.caf
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/New/Calypso.caf
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/New/Choo_Choo.caf
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/New/Descent.caf
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/New/Fanfare.caf
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/New/Ladder.caf
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/New/Minuet.caf
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/New/News_Flash.caf
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/New/Noir.caf
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/New/Sherwood_Forest.caf
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/New/Spell.caf
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/New/Suspense.caf
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/New/Telegraph.caf
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/New/Tiptoes.caf
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/New/Typewriters.caf
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/New/Update.caf
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/ReceivedMessage.caf
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/RingerChanged.caf
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/SIMToolkitCallDropped.caf
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/SIMToolkitGeneralBeep.caf
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/SIMToolkitNegativeACK.caf
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/SIMToolkitPositiveACK.caf
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/SIMToolkitSMS.caf
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/SentMessage.caf
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/Swish.caf
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/Tink.caf
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/Tock.caf
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/Voicemail.caf
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/alarm.caf
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/beep-beep.caf
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/begin_record.caf
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/begin_video_record.caf
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/ct-busy.caf
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/ct-call-waiting.caf
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/ct-congestion.caf
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/ct-error.caf
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/ct-keytone2.caf
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/ct-path-ack.caf
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/dtmf-0.caf
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/dtmf-1.caf
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/dtmf-2.caf
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/dtmf-3.caf
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/dtmf-4.caf
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/dtmf-5.caf
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/dtmf-6.caf
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/dtmf-7.caf
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/dtmf-8.caf
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/dtmf-9.caf
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/dtmf-pound.caf
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/dtmf-star.caf
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/end_record.caf
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/end_video_record.caf
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/jbl_ambiguous.caf
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/jbl_begin.caf
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/jbl_cancel.caf
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/jbl_confirm.caf
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/jbl_no_match.caf
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/lock.caf
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/long_low_short_high.caf
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/low_power.caf
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/mail-sent.caf
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/middle_9_short_double_low.caf
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/new-mail.caf
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/photoShutter.caf
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/shake.caf
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/short_double_high.caf
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/short_double_low.caf
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/short_low_high.caf
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/sms-received1.caf
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/sms-received2.caf
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/sms-received3.caf
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/sms-received4.caf
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/sms-received5.caf
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/sms-received6.caf
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/sq_alarm.caf
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/sq_beep-beep.caf
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/sq_lock.caf
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/sq_tock.caf
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/tweet_sent.caf
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/unlock.caf
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/ussd.caf
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/vc~ended.caf
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/vc~invitation-accepted.caf
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/vc~ringing.caf
```

Comment: Hi, I can't see those files in the iOS simulator. Are they only in the real devise?

Comment: Is the only way to get this list jailbreaking my device?

Comment: @DavidH Actually, you don't need to jailbreak. Use [this code](https://gist.github.com/neilco/a4b4a6b86bae1eff09b5) to list the sounds.

Comment: Xcode bundles simulator iOS system files within itself. This is different from `~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator` (user space files only)

System files are here:
`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Audio/UISounds`